# DES encryption - what happens if all sub-keys are the same?

Tags: algorithms, cryptography, encryption

What will happen if we change the DES encryrption algorithm to use the same key in each round ?

How will it affect the encryption - will it **only** make the encryption same as decryption or are the more effects ? I couldn't find any other possible effects in the DES standard description.

Thanks

Comment: Don’t do it. It’s a bad idea.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus - But what will be the effects ? besides making the decryption\encryption the same, what are the additional effects ? It's a theoretical question i have and can't figure out what else will happen

Comment: For one, it will make it easier to "guess" they key – all you need to do now is to guess one round key. Also, there might be a way to use a Pollard rho-type idea to somehow get input/output pairs for a single round.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus - In the first case, did you mean we now have to guess only 2^48 combinations ? But in this case you need to be able to have access to the encryption machine so you'll be able to force the 48-bit value into the K- variable in each round instead of feeding the key from outside. Do you assume such an access to the machine ? how likely is this scenario ? What can you really do with the K value itself in reality - usually all we can do is feed the key itself from outside the machine

Comment: Because knowing the K value doesn't mean we know how the permutation of K really works. If we see a "1" somewhere in K we can't know which position in the key it came from

Comment: Edit- also, K is 48-bit and there are 8 additional bits that will be missing, and we don't even know their positions in the real key because we don't know the positions of K's bits in the key either.

Comment: You do have access to the encryption machine. Its code is public.

Comment: But is the permutation table for the round keys also public ?

Comment: In case everything is public, that means you know only have to guess the additional 8 bits of the key ?  because the original input key is 56 bits (without parity) and not 48. That means a total of 2^48 + 2^8 which is far better than guessing 2^56. Right ?

Comment: Actually, I believe this question is more appropriate to [crypto.se]. The folks there would be able to help you better.

Comment: Thanks for helping out, i'll ask in Cryptography. Still, your answer is great :)

Comment: Close-voters, while this question probably is better suited to Cryptography, we have no policy (as far as I'm aware) that crypto questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

It will make the algorithm insecure.

It will be become vulnerable to slide attacks.

It will make encryption become equivalent to decryption, which is a weakness.  This is sometimes called a "[weak key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_key#Weak_keys_in_DES)"; with your scheme, every key will be "weak".

It will also reduce the keyspace to 48 bits, which is too small to be secure.